# how to access cloud-watch log of the lambda function call after invoking a lambda function from java client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm attempting to retrieve lambda function specific logs after invoking a lambda function. Is there an appropriate aws java sdk method to retrieve the logs of the lambda execution after invoking the function?

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS Lambda - Logging (Java)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html) documentation makes three recommendations:

> - Find logs in CloudWatch Logs. The context object (in the aws-lambda-java-core library) provides the getLogStreamName() and the getLogGroupName() methods. Using these methods, you can find the specific log stream where logs are written.

This case most matches your question. Get the CloudWatch Log Group and Log Stream from your [context object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-context-object.html), and then pass them into the SDK's [AWSLogsClient getLogEvents()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogsClient.html#getLogEvents-com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.GetLogEventsRequest-) method to retrieve your logs.

> - If you invoke a Lambda function via the console, the invocation type is always RequestResponse (that is, synchronous execution) and the console displays the logs that the Lambda function writes using the LambdaLogger object. AWS Lambda also returns logs from System.out and System.err methods.

This case is useful for manual testing/debugging from the console.

> - If you invoke a Lambda function programmatically, you can add the LogType parameter to retrieve the last 4 KB of log data that is written to CloudWatch Logs. For more information, see Invoke. AWS Lambda returns this log information in the x-amz-log-results header in the response. If you use the AWS Command Line Interface to invoke the function, you can specify the --log-type parameter with value Tail.

This case may be especially useful to you in a dev environment, and more readily available since you simply need to [setLogType](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/model/InvokeRequest.html#setLogType-java.lang.String-) on the Java SDK [InvokeRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/model/InvokeRequest.html). Then, on the response, just check [getLogResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/model/InvokeResult.html#getLogResult--).

Depending on your usage, think carefully before using this case in production. For example, will this leak your logs to your client? Even if it doesn't, is your volume sufficient enough to make this impractical?